# Fill the rest of the cell's width

Tags: html, css

Having the following HTML snippet

```
...
<td>
<input id="foo" type="text" style="width:20%">
&nbsp;
<input id="bar" type="text">
</td>
...
```

How can I make `bar` occupy the rest of the space, of the table cell? Making `width:100%` does not work, since it does 100% of the table cell, breaking into the next line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `width: 80%;`. You may still need to set margins to 0 and possibly use the `box-sizing` property.

Comment: Considering that there is a space in between that solution didn't work properly, unfortunately.

Comment: You may need to use the css calc function: `width: calc(80% - <number of pixels>);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flexbox` to set the default input behavior to `grow` or "fill" the remaining space. Simply define the display type for the parent `<td>` to `flex` and the grow behavior for each child element `<input>` to `flex-grow: 1`

```css
td { display: flex; }
input { flex-grow: 1; }
input#foo { width: 20%; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="foo" type="text" />
        <input id="bar" type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```